# How to create a collection holding tuples where each tuple must be unique?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using TypeScript and want to create a collection of objects. Each object has some properties. The combination of the properties must be unique inside the collection.

So these sample combinations would be valid

```
[
    [ 1, 2 ],
    [ 2, 1 ],
]
```

but adding another combination e.g. `[ 1, 2 ]` would throw an "key already exists" error.

Just as a sidenote: My question assumes there are 3 keys representing the "composite key". If there is a more flexible solution ... why not.

I tried to implement my own "map-like" structure as a showcase in JavaScript

```js
class MyCollection {
  constructor() {
    this.items = [];
  }

  add(firstTupleItem, secondTupleItem, thirdTupleItem) {
    if (this.has(firstTupleItem, secondTupleItem, thirdTupleItem)) {
      console.log(`ERR: Combination of [${firstTupleItem}, ${secondTupleItem}, ${thirdTupleItem}] already exists!`);

      return;
    }

    console.log(`Added combination of [${firstTupleItem}, ${secondTupleItem}, ${thirdTupleItem}]`);

    this.items.push([firstTupleItem, secondTupleItem, thirdTupleItem]);
  }

  has(firstTupleItem, secondTupleItem, thirdTupleItem) {
    return this.items.some(item =>
      item[0] === firstTupleItem &&
      item[1] === secondTupleItem &&
      item[2] === thirdTupleItem);
  }
}

const myCollection = new MyCollection();

/* passes as expected */

myCollection.add(1, 2, 3);
myCollection.add(2, 1, 3);
myCollection.add(3, 1, 2);
myCollection.add(1, 3, 2);

/* fails as expected */

myCollection.add(1, 2, 3);

console.log(myCollection.items);
```

Using a map might be faster but the value side seems to be wasted

```
class MyCustomMap extends Map<[number, number, number], [number, number, number]> {
    addItem(item: [number, number, number]) {
        super.set(item, item);
    }
}
```

Do I have to implement such a collection on my own or are there any better solutions? (using TypeScript)

Comment: Take a look at the [Tuples and Records proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-record-tuple) (currently at Stage 2). Once implemented, it'll allow you to do just that. You could check for an already existing implementation.

Comment: You just care about runtime implementation, right?  You're not necessarily interested in getting a *compile time* error if you try to add the same element multiple times, are you?  And I'm not sure why you want to throw a runtime error anyway instead of just silently discarding one of the duplicates like [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) does?  That is: why don't you just use `Set` on a JSON version of the tuple like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpv9Mw)?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, all the code gets executed during runtime. `Set` seems to be exactly what I'm looking for :) But it seems I can't use it directly? I created a TS demo https://jsfiddle.net/gsbevuo3/4/

Comment: What are you calling my attention to in there?  Is it that JSFiddle doesn't report compiler errors?  If so, you should use [the TS Playground](//tsplay.dev/wj4Z6m) instead which shows you that `"test"` gives a compiler error. If it's that `Set` allows duplicate array entries, it's because `Set` uses [value equality](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#value_equality), and `[1, 2] === [1, 2]` is false; they are two different objects.  Value equality is generally only useful on primitives, which is why I use a JSON string (but any unique key would work)

Comment: So do you want me to write up my version with `Set` as an answer?  Or do you have some other unmet use case?

Comment: I changed the JSFiddle settings to TypeScript but it seems that didn't work quite well ... yes, if you would like to feel free to post your answer for a `Set` :)

Comment: @jcalz I tried to implement a solution that is able to deal with the equality problem. Any suggestions or improvements? https://pastebin.com/by5irhvK (the TS playground url was too long...)

Comment: That works also if you'd rather convert both to and from a string instead of just to a string. I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), a JavaScript collection that contains at most one of any given value; if a value you `add()` to a `Set` is the same as one that already exists in the `Set`, nothing changes.   Unfortunately, the definition of what makes two values "the same" is not what you want it to be.  `Set` and the related [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) collection use ["same-value zero" equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#same-value-zero_equality).  For primitives like `string` and `number` such equality is fine, but for objects like `[1, 2]` (yes,  [`Arrays`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) are objects in JS), it amounts to *object identity* equality, similar to what you get with `===` (the difference is only around `NaN`):

```
const a = [1, 2];
const b = [1, 2];
console.log(a === b); // false

const c = a;
console.log(a === c); // true
const a = [1, 2];
```

This kind of makes sense, especially in light of possible property writes:

```
a[1] = 100;
console.log(a); // [1, 100]
console.log(b); // [1, 2]
console.log(c); // [1, 100]
```

But since you're not planning to hold onto array references and modify their contents (are you?), you'd much rather have something like your own custom equality function, where two arrays are equal if their contents are equal.

And unfortunately, `Set` and `Map` [do not support this directly](https://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-maps-sets.html#why-can%E2%80%99t-i-configure-how-maps-and-sets-compare-keys-and-values%3F).

---

If you want something like this, you'll need to implement it yourself.  One way to do this is to come up with a function `f()` which converts your objects to a primitive key value such that `f(o1) === f(o2)` if and only if `o1` and `o2` should be considered "equal".  The easiest way to do this for arrays-of-primitives is to use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

So if your objects are of type `Props`:

```
type Props = [number, number, number];
```

Then the conversion function `f()` can be written as `propsToKey()`:

```
function propsToKey(props: Props): string {
    return JSON.stringify(props);
}
```

Now, in your class, you hold onto a `Set` of those keys instead of the objects.  Or, you can hold onto a `Map` keyed by the keys whose values are the objects, so you can still return the original object if you want.  You wrap every `Set` method you care about in something that calls `propsToKey()` appropriately.  Oh, and since it seems you want your `add()` method to take a variadic number of arguments (e.g., 3 for `[number, number, number]`) instead of an array, then we should use rest/spread syntax where appropriate.

Okay, let's do this to implement `MyCollection`:

```
class MyCollection {
    private items: Map<string, Props> = new Map();
    add(...props: Props) {
        this.items.set(propsToKey(props), props);
        return this;
    }
    clear() {
        this.items.clear();
    }
    delete(...props: Props) {
        return this.items.delete(propsToKey(props));
    }
    forEach(cb: (...props: Props) => void) {
        return this.items.forEach(v => cb(...v));
    }
    has(...props: Props) {
        return this.items.has(propsToKey(props));
    }
    get size() {
        return this.items.size;
    }
    values() {
        return this.items.values();
    }
}
```

Let's test it:

```
const myCollection = new MyCollection();
myCollection.add(1, 2, 3);
myCollection.add(2, 1, 3);
myCollection.add(3, 1, 2);
myCollection.add(1, 3, 2);
console.log(Array.from(myCollection.values())) // [[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2], [1, 3, 2]] 

myCollection.add(1, 2, 3);
console.log(Array.from(myCollection.values())) // [[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2], [1, 3, 2]]
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA2gRgDQwEwF0DcAsAFCiSwBGSqmOBJZEIANgKYB0zIA5gBQKJBMCgEp8MAPQSYAMzjMIrEg3DQYwanCKlVLDlz4ChwMZOlQATgFclxEnHS5qaAAwvtjPZx79TUmliuLrgqkF4GvKLi-uhYeKFMbN58JtHSsTBBIXbE-gAmrDIAlmCsMFAAFqyKJFAAngAOZQAKFiANENQoYFYAthSsFlg9-YPDfQMW9MQyVmDAUEXgMA1tHQAqIADSrHW8q+0QAFwwrYciJ9AWJdwwAN4kME8wFqxQVhZgMABSAMoA8gA5dhXG5FGR7A4dMQkAC+ylIzDgEE6AFk6gBhFhsBZLL4PYjPFbXABucCgZSKFN6xxgqLgDQAPKCwNwsGcOgA+ailADudIZvBhhOecDyeV47ClUNpHIgInujyJz0qRQg7CprBpILe+zWEE2O0h+pEWBlwuVz1e70+5Qqau0RPhIqewDYcAsQsVLuVqvVmu1btYHqFjuezqJBTYFMl0v1JzlCoJlqe1o+Xz9Gup6qjb1YesOht2BehFvDSqeMhAFgAonBgBVeMAKCdY+wZQmTUhuSSQEU8kmK8q07bMwH1VXa-XGyTu+oKG2SSIy08I88Ksi2x3Tl3kymRxn7f7s+wNxASwbtsXzSuYGuntw3jAIEUAF75wc+okHu1qrNa9UX3fMNVyHMlmBsc9PxTF43nTX9jwA9hwMg0Mh2dZ0ElgXpMWxVhcWWZA+TpXDmBxRZwDQ4gcKxMj8IosB2DFCVaGwLAAGZhRovCCMY5jeDYzIOK40jyLxJjxV4djAjiETaLE8AJJYjjZI8XQkgiABBCwLDgOp2BkNpel4bi6N45D5FQ5cFRiDJBPY3AsBQQTaAcpzpKEugnNcuJcCcBFTIUvjJNY4S1LCDSfG03T9MMkBjMC+jxJQ6ohWXMxUDsjjHNQFzsvcmSvICGAPLwJwgA)

Comment: in addition to your answer I added some types https://pastebin.com/R0hHMN3V But I think this class needs a better name. And maybe someone else implemented this already?

Comment: @jcalz or maybe something like this? https://pastebin.com/VmHcwsgz but I'm struggling with the delete override. And maybe my solution is slower because of the `has` implementation

Comment: Edit: https://pastebin.com/TrDzEsM9 but my solution is way slower I guess (especially `delte`)